# How to use RFM along with Predictive model?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, clustering, data-transformation, descriptive-statistics

I am looking to segment my customers based on their transactional data with us.

Based on google search, I came to know about RFM matrix, which records Recency, Frequency and Monetary value-based scores.

This seems like a powerful technique based on my initial reading. However, it looks like it is just descriptive analysis of historical data.

How can I use RFM to predict for future data points?

Using ML can help me predict the factors that influence the customer to be in one of the segments

Is there any recent advances in RFM method where ML techniques like clustering or classification can be applied for the purpose of prediction on future data points?

Is there any RFM-ML tutorial that you can share?

Comment: What did you intend to put in your title?  Something is missing.

Comment: i updated. It is RFM , Recency, Frequency and Monetary